# authenticate jwt token created by next-auth in nestjs backend with passportjs

Tags: next.js, passport.js, nestjs, next-auth

I have a nextjs react app. It uses next-auth to create JWT. This app will send post requests to a nestjs backend. I'm planning to send my next-auth JWT as bearer token in request header and my nestjs backend will need to validate it using passportjs.

Is this a reasonable use case? Can passportjs validate my next-auth JWT?

Comment: Have you tried? And ensured that `next-auth` and the `passport` configuration inside the NestJS application have the exact same secret?

Comment: Hey @JayMcDoniel, you can check it out  https://dev.to/muratas/creating-nextjs-jwt-token-using-ldap-for-authentication-authorization-use-it-in-nestjs-graphql-backend-417a

Answer (score 3):

I've written an article on this. Sample projects also included.

https://dev.to/muratas/creating-nextjs-jwt-token-using-ldap-for-authentication-authorization-use-it-in-nestjs-graphql-backend-417a